# Не видит библиотеки при смене набора инструментов платформы C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

В общем, проблема в следующем. Есть задание написать простое приложение на чистом WinAPI. Самое задание проще некуда, но я столкнулся с тем, что целевая платформа - Windows XP (SP 3), а моя - Windows 10. При попытке изменения набора инструментов платформы студия перестает видеть библиотеки random, sstream и даже string.h, инклюд которого лежит в автоматически созданном Guiddef.h. Прошу помощи, может кто сталкивался с таким уже?

Comment: Ну а вы изменяете на набор инструментов платформы, который у вас установлен?

Comment: Сообщите версию студии